# MinGW Link Single EXE

Tags: c++, mingw

I installed MinGW and I just want to link my program into a single EXE file.  I want to be able to give this EXE file to someone without having to worry about all the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll,or any other DLL.  Is there a way to statically link all the required libraries into a single EXE?

I am developing on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-static` option when linking with libraries, and for libgcc and libstdc++ use the following:

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```