# Compile for distribution on Windows 7 using NetBeans C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, distribution

I made a application in Netbeans on windows 7. I want to run it on another system but it seems to have lots of dll's it depends on. The compiler tool kit I am using is MinGW, and the first two missing dll's are form that. I only get one missing dll file per run so it is a lot of back and forth to find them all.

Is there a way to list all the dll's that my executable depends on?

Is there a way to compile it so that it does not depend on so many of them (ie compiles the code into the exe)?

Thanks

Comment: See [MinGW Link Single EXE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222325/mingw-link-single-exe/9222388#9222388).

Comment: @JesseGood That will help. I guess I could compile it myself, but is there any way to tell NetBeans to do this? Also is there anyway to find out what libraries I need to link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu bar, select **Menu** -> **Project Properties**. Then in the categories column, expand the node that says **Build** and select **Linker**. Then in command line under additional options, add `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`. This will statically link the C and C++ libraries for you. You can also add other libraries with the `-static` option.

There are tools to help you find dependencies for you, but for windows dlls, I usually just look at MSDN. Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency) that talks about some tools if you want to use them.